Changing coefficient names in plot_summs() with multiple models
I have three different models for which I want to display a coefficient for each with the plot_summs() function from the jtools package. I want to rename each coefficient within the plot_summs() function with the coefs argument, however, when I try to do so, I either get an error or only the "Export-Oriented Sector" label gets applied and the other two coefficient labels are empty in the final output.
Here is my code:
plot_summs(model1, model3, model2, 
                         coefs = c("Non-tradable Sector" = post, "Import-Oriented Sector"  = post, "Export-Oriented Sector" = post), 
                         #ci_level = 0.95,
                         inner_ci_level = 0.85,
                         robust = TRUE, 
                         cluster = "ID",
                         model.names = c("Model 1:Non-tradable sector as reference ", "Model 2: Export-oriented sector as reference", "Model 3: Import-oriented as reference")) + 
  labs(y = "")

Then I get the following error:

Error: object 'post' not found

If I add "" to post, like this:
plot_summs(model1, model3, model2, 
                         coefs = c("Non-tradable Sector" = "post", "Import-Oriented Sector"  = "post", "Export-Oriented Sector" = "post"), 
                         #ci_level = 0.95,
                         inner_ci_level = 0.85,
                         robust = TRUE, 
                         cluster = "ID",
                         model.names = c("Model 1:Non-tradable sector as reference ", "Model 2: Export-oriented sector as reference", "Model 3: Import-oriented as reference")) + 
  labs(y = "")

then only the label for the coefficient of "Export-Oriented Sector" gets changed but for the other two coefficients the labels are empty in the final output.
The coefficients that I want to display are called the same in the three models, I guess that this is causing a conflict. However, it would be really unconvenient to give the "post" variable a different name for each model before running the models.
How can I manage to change all coefficient labels in the plot_summs()function?

You could fix the names after you build the plot, e.g., x = plot_summs(... and x$data <- x$data %>% mutate(term = case_when(term == "post" & model == "Model 1" ~ "Non-tradable Sector",..., TRUE ~ term) %>% as.factor) (Where ... is the other settings you want changed.) Then plot as usual.
